# Команды для элементов в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе используется несколько `ItemsControl` с переопределенным стилем, элементы которых кнопки, которые делают примерно одно и то же: по клику на кнопку, выбранный элемент должен удаляться из коллекции, привязанной к `ItemsSource`.

Из-за того, что привязываются разные коллекции, то для каждого `ItemsControl` я делаю свою команду удаления. И каждый `ItemsControl` у меня выглядит примерно так:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" >
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ItemsControlMainStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                                            Command="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext.OperationsVM.RemoveElementCommand}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```

То есть я дополняю основной стиль `ItemsControlMainStyle` и привязываю нужную команду. Код получается очень громоздкий. Интуитивно кажется, что можно сделать все более лаконично и этот кусок кода со стилем и привязкой команд вынести в `ItemsControlMainStyle`, а нужную команду забирать уже из свойства. Но вот с реализацией такого подхода у меня проблемы, ведь у `ItemsControl` нет свойства `Command`.

Подскажите, как такое сделать (и можно ли)?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что подразумевается под `Из-за того, что привязываются разные коллекции`

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Есть 4 разных `ObservableCollection` во `ViewModel`, которые биндятся  к 4-м разным `ItemsControl`. Каждый элемент представлен кнопкой, при клике на которую элемент должен удалятся из привязанной коллекции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, стандартный хак для таких случаев — использование `Tag`.

Получится вот как. В `ItemsControlMainStyle` добавьте

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                                Command="{Binding Tag,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Теперь можно привязывать команду к `ItemsControl`'у:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
              Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlMainStyle}"
              Tag="{Binding DeleteCountryCommand}"/>
```

---

Кстати, непонятно, почему вы используете `ItemContainerStyle`, а не `ItemTemplate`:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                    Command="{Binding Tag,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Иллюстрация к коду]

ViewModel подключена в XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Список с кнопками такой

```
 <ListBox Height="284" Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="27" Width="186"
             ItemsSource="{Binding StrList}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Button
                        FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                        FontSize="12" Content="&#xE106;"
                        Margin="10,0"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCountryCommand, ElementName=window}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Во ViewModel

свойство для списка

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _StrList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> StrList
    {
        get { return _StrList; }
        set
        {
            _StrList = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StrList)));
        }
    }
```

Команда для удаления

```
private RelayCommand<string> _DeleteCountryCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> DeleteCountryCommand
    {
        get { return _DeleteCountryCommand = _DeleteCountryCommand ??
                new RelayCommand<string>(OnDeleteCountry, CanDeleteCountry); }
    }
    private bool CanDeleteCountry(string arg)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void OnDeleteCountry(string obj)
    {
        StrList.Remove(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос был в том, как прибиндить команду в стиле и  чтобы  этот стиль был универсален. Повторюсь, у меня 4 коллекции и 4 `ItemsControl` и команда удаления элемента для каждой из коллекций своя. В этом и сложность для меня, что приходится часть стиля, где биндится команда, выносить.

Comment: Вы спокойно, логично подумайте над этим:"...как прибиндить команду в стиле и чтобы этот стиль был универсален." и как это соотносится с этим: " и команда удаления элемента для каждой из коллекций своя". Следовательно, раз команда своя, она не может быть забайдена в универсальном стиле. Байдинг команды должен быть независим от стиля.

Comment: В том и суть, что команда биндится не напрямую, а через свойство родительского элемента.  
Что-то вроде `<ItemsControl Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" />`. А в стиле уже забираем эту команду для удаления элемента из коллекции. Вопрос в том, как сделать это.

Comment: Извините, но все это мне напоминает: "...мы не ищем легких путей...", "у нас проблем нет кроме тех, которые мы придумали сами себе".

Comment: Проблема в том, что это 1) копирование кода 2) громоздкий код.

Comment: Хорошо, Команда С Параметром, что вы думаете об этом?

Comment: У команды ведь уже есть параметр — имя удаляемого элемента. Класть туда еще и название коллекции из которой нужно удалить элемент? Тоже как-то не элегантно :) Или я не так вас понял?

Comment: Я примерно это подразумевал, только не название коллекции, а любой отличительный признак элемента, по которому определять к какой коллекции он относится. А вот насчет вашего:"ведь у ItemsControl нет свойства Command", к элементам у которых нет команды прикручивают (поведения) Behaviors.

Comment: Если с помощью этого можно решить мою задачу, был бы благодарен вам за пример. Не приходилось сталкиваться с поведениеями. Читал лишь, что (вроде бы) их проще реализовать через Blend.

Comment: Лучше с точки зрения наполнения базы знаний этого сайта если вы зададите отдельный вопрос именно на тему Behaviors.

Comment: Очевидно, что ваш ответ это вовсе не то, о чем спрашивал @maxwell . Вы привели код, который практически в точности повторяет то, что автор показал в вопросе.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper что вы предлагаете? Покажите свой вариант.

Comment: Да пока задача не слишком понятна, чтобы что-то конкретное предлагать...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper именно такой исход я и предполагал. Как критиковать так все горазды, а вот хоть какой-нибудь код показать - сразу в кусты.

Comment: @Bulson ваш ответ даже критиковать не нужно, т.к. вы просто повторили за автором (о чем уже говорил ранее) или вы не согласны?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper У автора байдинг команды был через стиль. Автор просил более простой вариант, т.к. "интуитивно" предполагал, что можно сделать иначе. Я предложил свой вариант подробно расписав его с расчетом на начинающих пользователей данного ресурса, т.к. не все представляют как это вообще делается. Автору этот вариант не понравился, хорошо с этим можно согласится. Но вот вы, что вы конкретно полезного сделали? `"Вы привели код, который практически в точности повторяет то, что автор показал ".Equals("пердеж в лужу") == true` - верно, доказано практикой. Подпись. Печать.

Comment: Не - а. Автор просил не более простой вариант и даже не провести ревью. Прочтите вопрос внимательно. А затем еще раз и еще. До тех пор пока не поймете, что автор хочет избежать копипаст - разработки. Вы же просто перенесли шаблон из стиля. Вариант не так плох - код, конечно, немного сократился... но это совсем не то, что хотел видеть @maxwell . Вы привели куски кода без малейших комментариев к ним, так что ваша апелляция к начинающим пользователям отклонена.